# How do I add the Quickbooks Online PaymentService?

Tags: c#, quickbooks-online

I saw another post here about using the PaymentService for Quickbooks Online.  I'm currently making charges using a JObject and passing it directly to an httpWebRequest.

I saw this post and realize that I might not have to do this.

[Quickbooks API - How to create a charge using stored credit card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47979320/quickbooks-api-how-to-create-a-charge-using-stored-credit-card)

I'm currently using the IppDotNetSdkForQuickBooksApiV3 v7.5.0 nuget package.  I've been able to use the QueryService to access invoices and company records, but I couldn't figure out a better way to create payments before.

I've tried using

```
PaymentService paymentService = new PaymentService();
```

But it can't find a reference to PaymentService.

Specifically I'm needing to add the ability for the customers to store credit cards and make recurring payments.  I know the api doesn't allow for making a recurring charge, but I can run a regular process to charge the stored card as needed.